# canActivate always taking to login form in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router-guards

I am new to angular. I am using canActivate guard but when I apply it to the route, it always takes me to the login page despite the guard returning true.

Please help.

guard code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private routes: Router) { }
  canActivate(
    
    alert('blocked');
    return true;
  }
}
```

**Route:**

```
{
    path: 'list',
    component: BatchListComponent, 
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
```

Comment: How ```return false;``` can return true?

Comment: Show all your routes in your app-routing.module.ts please

Comment: maybe it's a different place in the code taking you to the login page

Comment: Hi, I am using the specific module and routing. And when I remove the guard in the route, it works fine.

Comment: Is it me or your can activate function will not compile?

Comment: Since your implementation of AuthGuard always returns a boolean, there's no way it can redirect you to a login page, it just stops the navigation. There's clearly something else in your application that is not working as you expect and redirecting you to the login page.

Comment: Thanks @Ibsn. Your comment was valuable in resolving my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Interface that a class can implement to be a guard deciding if a route can be activated. If all guards return true, navigation continues. If any guard returns false, navigation is cancelled. If any guard returns a UrlTree, the current navigation is cancelled and a new navigation begins to the UrlTree returned from the guard.

You're auth logic is not correct and it would be better to not return anything right now till you are prepared to do so.  Otherwise it will continually fail.

https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate